# uWSGI restarts attached processes without stopping old ones

Tags: python, django, multithreading, uwsgi

I have a web app that requires several custom consumer scripts to run in parallel with the main Django app. Since I am already running Django app using uWSGI, I figured that I would use emperor mode and attach-daemon config to start my other processes at the same time as the main app. It works fine for every process except one. The difference between this process and others is that this process forks several worker threads that pick jobs from a queue that the master process fills. The relevant code looks like this

```
def worker(q):
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        ... do things with the item ...
        q.task_done()

def heartbeat():
    the_queue = Queue()
    # create the thread pool
    for n in range(NUMBER_OF_THREADS):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(the_queue,))
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

    while True:
        # mark the start time
        start_time = datetime.utcnow()

        # use Django ORM to get a list of devices
        for device in Device.objects.all():
            the_queue.put(device)
        # wait for workers to deal with things
        the_queue.join()
        # mark the end time
        end_time = datetime.utcnow()
        time.sleep(SOME_CALCULATED_AMOUNT)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    heartbeat()
```

My uWSGI config for this process looks like this

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
enable-threads=true

chdir=somedir

uid=ubuntu
gid=ubuntu

pidfile=somepath
daemonize=somepath

env=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
attach-daemon2 = cmd=python3 heartbeat/heartbeat.py,control=true
```

I have tried it both with enabled threads and without and I tried it with regular attach-daemon and both result in the same thing. The process starts fine, but after a while I will see two and then more processes spawned without anything showing up in the logs. If I stop uWSGI only one of the spawned processes is killed, the others keep running. It is almost as if uWSGI thinks the process died and restarts it, when in fact the process never died.

I know the process implementation is not the best. If nothing else helps, I will try and re-implement it to spawn threads as needed rather than keeping a thread pool.

Comment: If uWSGI restarts the "vassal" it may be that your "main" thread doesn't send heartbeat in (what uWSGI belies is) a "timely manner". To isolate, try turning the option [`heartbeat`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html?highlight=mercy#heartbeat) off in your config.

Comment: The heartbeats are not for uWSGI, these are for our system. uWSGI is not and should not be aware of what the process actually does. And there is no option heartbeat in the config.

Comment: Ah sorry, your `heartbeat` function was indeed the source of my confusion. Can you elaborate on what exactly goes wrong? I.e does uWSGI spawn the first process as intended and the thread pool work as intended? For what amount of time? Then what happens with the existing process/threads? What is the state of the Django app? What is the state of the other processes spawned?

Comment: Also, take a look at the [**Notes** section in the docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Emperor.html#notes). This mentions you can send `SIGUSR1` signal to check on vassal status, as well as some other helpful notes.

Comment: The process spawns, then something happens and uWSGI forgets about this process and spawns another, without killing the first one. Happens a few times a day, so these processes accumulate and there should only be one running at any given time.

All other processes seem to be OK

Comment: A very common issue that manifests as "zombie process" (which seem to be what you describe) is if an Exception is raised in one of the worker threads; this would cause the main thread to ignore SIGINT which uWSGI may attempt to send.

Comment: Hmm... why would the main process ignore the SIGINT even if one of the threads dies?

Comment: Control is never returned to main thread so it cannot handle the signal. I modified your script to demo that, however am AFK. Will push when at computar

Comment: [Here is the simplified script above](https://gist.github.com/asfaltboy/6286d792b79d155adbc3a125d24a4b81) which raises an exception. Try running and sending SIGINT to the process while running and after hitting the exception. You can probably simply catch the exception to work around this behavior.